# Let my Windows Phone use my PC internet connection

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, internet-connection

I am creating a  Windows Phone 8 app for the 1st time.

I am using VS2013.  My app talks to my server and acquires an image.  Is there a way for my Phone to use my internet connection at all?

I use to be able to do this with Windows Mobile Compact CF.  I cannot see how to do this in my ide?

What I need is to run my app via my IDE/Debugger and for my mobile device to use my PCs internet connection as my GPRS connectivity is poor where I am.

Thanks

Comment: @closer is that better? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uses Windows Phone 7.x with Zune, you can.

But when Windows Phone 8 comes, you cannot.

You can use the Windows Phone Emulator, it will use your PC's internet connection, or you might be able to share your PC's internet connection via wireless or Bluetooth (with some hardware on your PC).

Comment: Hi, that answered my question so will accept your answer. The only problem I have is that I am using VM Ware so I cannot get the emulators to run :(